# Import Partial & Comment Out in SASS

Tags: css, sass

I have a `_reset.scscs` partial that I want to import into my `app.scss` file but I want to comment it out so that the final `app.css` looks something like:

```
/* If you need a reset uncomment the lines below */
/* html, body, etc { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;} */

.foo {
  background: blue;
}
```

#### Edit #1

**_reset.scss**

```
html, body, etc { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;}
```

(notice that the contents `_reset.scss` are not commented out. I want the user of my library to still be able to `@import "reset";` and the code not be commented out. So I guess I'm essentially asking if sass can import and then wrap that import in a comment? If not how would one accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

That is what import is for.

```
@import 'reset';
```

Just comment it out like you want in your _reset.scss file and it will import it fine as long as you are using css comments ( /* comment */ ) not sass comments ( // sass comment ). sass comments do not get output when compiled.

You can find documentation about sass comments here: 
http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#comments